# How to split the line and print the output after the line?(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I want to print the code that is always in the next line to the message `Your One-time Verification Code is:`

An Example of the message is:

```
Your One-time Verification Code is:

366522
```

The output should be `366522`

Which python string method can be used to receive this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.split` or `.rsplit` method is one solution that can get you there:

```py
s = """\
Your One-time Verification Code is:

366522\
"""

# Split on newline, and pass limit=1 so we stop after N=1 splits. Note that
# the split is performed from the end of the string, since we use rsplit.

print(s.rsplit('\n', 1)[-1])
# 366522
```

If you have more lines after the verification code, use `.split` instead:

```py
s = """\
Your One-time Verification Code is:

366522

Testing, testing
1 2 3
"""

# Split on newline, and pass limit=3 so we stop after N=3 splits. Then grab
# the third element (the last line that we split)

print(s.split('\n', 3)[2])
# 366522
```

Comment: If the message contains more sentences, and I only want the next line after the ` Your One-time Verification Code is : `

Comment: Hmm, in that case I wouldn't suggest `rsplit`. Using `split` with limit=3 and retrieving the 3rd element/line should get you the verification code

Answer (score 2):

You can use string split method ([link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)). \n is a character, that specifies a newline, so you can use it to split the string.

```
code = your_string.split('/n')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

BY using the .split or .rsplit method